# What is the meaning of $(@:.o=.c) in a GNU Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The following Make command is in a Makefile I'm reviewing:

```
%.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(@:.o=.c) -o $@
```

What does the `$(@:.o=.c)` variable in this Make command mean?

I'm aware that `$@` is an Automatic Variable as explained by [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables). However, I still wasn't able to figure out what `$(@:.o=.c)` meant by searching around the docs.

Comment: See: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html

Comment: Thanks! Just didn't know what to search :)

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted by [@MadScientist's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74857153/what-is-the-meaning-of-o-c-in-a-gnu-makefile/74857234#comment132107375_74857153), the relevant section of the documentation is here:

> See: [gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html)

Here is a snippet from that section of the docs:

> 6.3.1 Substitution References
>
> A substitution reference substitutes the value of a variable with
> alterations that you specify. It has the form ‘$(var:a=b)’ (or
> ‘${var:a=b}’) and its meaning is to take the value of the variable
> var, replace every a at the end of a word with b in that value, and
> substitute the resulting string.
>
> When we say “at the end of a word”, we mean that a must appear either
> followed by whitespace or at the end of the value in order to be
> replaced; other occurrences of a in the value are unaltered. For
> example:
>
> ```
> foo := a.o b.o l.a c.o
> bar := $(foo:.o=.c)
> ```
>
> sets ‘bar’ to ‘a.c b.c l.a c.c’. See Setting Variables.

In my example, the value represented by the Automatic Variable `$@` will be converted to `$@.c` if it is of the form `$@.o`.

For more info on what the Automatic Variable `$@` means, refer to [this part of the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).